# Rust: "multiple inheritance"?

Tags: oop, inheritance, rust, traits

I am trying to do the following in rust:

```rust
trait A {
    fn _add(&mut self, x: i32);
}

impl<T> std::ops::Add for T
where
    T: A + Clone,
{
    type Output = T;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut ans = self.clone();
        ans._add(rhs);
        return ans;
    }
}

struct IntMod2 {
    x: i32,
}

impl Clone for IntMod2 {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { x: self.x }
    }
}

impl A for IntMod2 {
    fn _add(&mut self, x: i32) {
        self.x += x;
        self.x = self.x % 2;
    }
}
```

The aim is that we can add two objects of type `IntMod2` like `x+y`.

However, it does not compile. The error message is:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> src/lib.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<T> std::ops::Add for T
  |      ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

This has something to do with the "orphan rule", which ensures other codes do not break current crate. **However, in this case, such breaking change can never happen** because A belongs to the current crate, so the rule in this case is not having the benefit described by the documentations.

How can I achieve the "double inheritance" what I want?

Comment: What if a foreign type want's to implement `A`, `Add` and `Clone`, then you'd have conflicting implementations of `Add` that's why this is not allowed.

Comment: There was some discussion on "sealed traits" that will allow that, but currently this is not possible.

Comment: Notes: 1. Since you receive `self` by value in `Add` there is no need to clone it (you'd need clone only when implementing `Add` for `&T`. 2. Your `Clone` implementation could easily have been `#[derive(Clone)]`d

Comment: you can't do a blanked implementation for a trait you don't own and this will never change.

Comment: why can't you just implement add for your struct ? why do you want use a custom trait ?

Comment: that very weird but you could do that https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7de8dbed5b2dd5d90d008dfb4525bd3